# bash script , how to optionally log to log file, and/or console

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to create a bash script that prints results optionally to the console (STDOUT and STDERR), a log file or both.

I've got the getops working to set the options, but I can't seem to figure out the command.  So far, I have something like this:

```
# default logs to both
export LOG_COMMAND=" 2>&1 | tee ${INSTALL_LOG}"

if [ "$ONLY_CONSOLE" == "true" ] ; then
  export LOG_COMMAND=""
elif  [ "$ONLY_LOG" == "true" ] ; then
  export LOG_COMMAND=" | tee ${INSTALL_LOG}"
fi

echo "Starting script" ${LOG_COMMAND}
# ... then do more stuff ...
```

This script prints this to the console only and nothing to the log file:

```
Starting script 2>&1 | tee scriptfile.log
```

But I would like the script to print to the console and to the file scriptfile.log.

Has anyone done this before?  It appears that the echo command is processing the ${LOG_COMMAND} as a variable.

Replacing the echo command with this works will print both:

```
echo "Starting script" 2>&1 | tee -a ${INSTALL_LOG}
```

However, this means that there is no option to print to console, log file, or both.  It is hard coded to print to both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is definitely more than one way to do this, but the easiest may be to keep things simple.

After getopts is done and you've figured out what goes where, you use that to call `main` in the correct manner, and put all the rest of your logic in main (or called from main).  For example:

```
main() {
  # do stuff
  # call other functions
  # do more stuff
}

if [ $ONLY_CONSOLE -eq 0 ]
then
  main
elif [ $ONLY_LOG -eq 0 ]
then
  main > $INSTALL_LOG 2>&1
else # both
  main 2>&1 | tee $INSTALL_LOG
fi
```

The alternative is an arcane combination of execs and other flow, but for a small number of options, this just makes the most sense to me.